# Customized Hyperledger Explorer is possible...?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger

I successfully completed a hyperledger composer and working it well.
I just created explorer for the same network using the git https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer. This explorer is slow to load. I just decide to create own explorer using Node.js . My questions is

1. How to get blocks number, hash, etc using node.js.(I already visited the site  [node api link](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/Channel.html#queryBlock__anchor) . But do not see any example how to use it)??
2. Have any idea to increase the speed of existing hyperledger explorer.??

Please give any suggestion for my problem. Thanks in advance

Fabric 1.1.0

Composer 0.19.16

Os: Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyperledger Explorer has to traverse the blockchain to build its view of the ledger (stored in a PostgreSQL DB). If you have a large number of blocks, this can take some time. However, once this has been built, new blocks should be picked up as fast as your network can supply them.

However, if you want to look at improving it, why not just start with the existing code? This is after all the whole point of open-source software :)

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger explorer is provide API such as http://localhost:8080/blocks/{channel name}/{block number}

We can easily implement the front end and call the API at back end. Hope you help you. Thanks